# Navigate from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I am working an android app that has one activity and multiple fragment so I added a lockout feature which locks out the user if there is no interaction in ten minutes. I did this by creating an activity that extends AppCompatActivity and navigates to lockScreenActivity if there is no interaction with the app. Now after the app is unlocked from a web socket I want to navigate back to the activity retaining the current fragment before navigation. How should I go about it.

Searches in stack overflow suggests that I do:

startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));

This does not work for me, calling finish on LockScreenActivity did not work too.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at Jetpack Navigation lib

Comment: Thank you IgorGanapolsky, I will check it out, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going from a `Fragment` to your `MainActivity` you should do this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), mFragmentFavorite.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But if you are going from `Activity` to `Fragment` , do this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, mFragmentFavorite.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

if you are doing a `finish()` going to `lockActivity`  and doing another finish inside `lockActivity` , there is no activityes in the stack to inflate, maybe thats why is not working for you

Comment: So in this case mFragmentFavorite is a fragment?

Comment: no necesary, that is a random class, from fragment to activity you should use getActivity() and from activity to fragment this, or the name of the activity .this

Comment: if you want mFragmentFavorite to be a fragment , you should change from FragmentActivity in your extend for Fragment

Comment: Can’t I just navigate to the parent activity of the fragment?

Comment: you're right i was doing: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);

Comment: Hope it helped !

Comment: Yeah it did, Thanks for helping.

Comment: it is not possible to move from Activity to Fragment using 'Intent', for that we must use 'FragmentTransaction'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back from Activity to Fragment.
This is very simple just override onBackPressed() in your activity and call onBackPressed where you want. See my code bellow this will more clear your concept.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    }

 //now call onBackPressed to navigate from activity to fragment
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```